# How do you make line breaks hidden when the <details> tag is open, and vice versa?

Tags: html, css

[Optimal and unoptimal products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGoYE.png)
Is there a specific CSS or HTML property that can make the line breaks appear upon the <details> tag opening? Before opening the <details> tag, there's an awkward space.

```css
.a {
  /*put anything else here*/
}

.sbr:before {
  font-size: 1px;
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre-line;
}

details {
  color: #444;
  font-family: Arial;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#nav,
#nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#nav a {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none
}

#nav a.active,
#nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

#nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666
}

#nav li {
  border-right: 1px solid #999
}

#nav a {
  color: #666
}

#nav a.active,
#nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ddd
}

.dop {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt
}

#nav {
  font-size: 90%
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Items</summary>
  <div class=sbr></div>
  <ul id="nav">
    <div class=dop>
      <li><a href="">Index</a></li>
      <li><a href="">List</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Table</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Font demo</a></li>
      <li><a href="">More versions</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Other stuff</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Old UI</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Folder Directory</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Temporary Notepad</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Dark Mode</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Bookmarklets</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Double Target Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Theme Color Page</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</details>
<div class=a><br><br></div>
foo bar foo bar foo bar
<!-- a class was intentionally left blank -->
```

Edit: The '<div class=a><br><br></div> is there to not make the 'foo bar foo bar foo bar' go right beside the 'Theme Color Page' link on bigger screens.

Comment: You mean the gap we can see if we "run code snippet" between "Items" and "foo bar foo bar.." ? which is obviously comming from `<div class=a><br><br></div>`

Comment: Yea maybe an image of what you hope for? I see two explicit `<br>` immediately after the `details` in that `div` so a bit confusing what you're referring to.

Comment: @caramba Yes, that's the gap that I'm talking about.

Comment: @ChrisW. How would I use an image?

Comment: remove the `<div class=a><br><br></div>` or elaborate why it is there. For now (with the information given) that is causing the gap which you don't want and does nothing else

Comment: @79kep as in an image that would help us visualize what you want it to look like, since at the moment the spacing you're mentioning looks intentional?

Comment: @ChrisW. Got the desired image.

Comment: just delete your last div

Comment: @DCR Without that last div, the 'foo bar foo bar foo bar' goes right beside the 'Theme Color Page' link on bigger screens.

Comment: then delete the div and add 1 < br>

Comment: @DCR
Dan Mullin's answer worked, and only 1 <br> does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this and remove the div with the line breaks.

```css
details {margin-bottom: 20px;}

details[open] {margin-bottom: 0;}
```

Or vice versa depending on when you want the space and when you don’t.